# How is this design pattern called

Tags: java, design-patterns

what is the name of the Design pattern. Simple example

```
public interface SomeObject{

    public void call();
}

public UnknownDesignPatternImpl implements SomeObject(

    List<SomeObject> objects;

    public UnknownDesignPatternImpl(List<SomeObject> objs){
        objects = obj
    }

    public void call(){
        for (SomeObject obj: objects){
            obj.call();
        }
    }
}
```

it implements the same Interface but delegates calls to a List of interface objects

Comment: looks like command too

Comment: Next time you have this question, first scan through [this list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern#Classification_and_list).

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik thanks, saw that list the first time, but its hard to googe something without knowing the name...

Comment: I googled for "list of design patterns"---that's because I couldn't remember the name of your pattern.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an implementation of the [Composite Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) - an object implements an interface and delegates to a collection of other objects implementing the same interface.

Answer (score 2):

It's called **Composite**

More information here:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-composite

Answer (score 1):

Are you talking about the delegation pattern? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern

Comment: no, I guess Composite is better, because it seems that `Delegeate Pattern` maps only 1 to 1 relations

Answer (score 0):

It could be very similiar to **Command**

References:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/design-patterns-command